# How to check the layout and inflate in android fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-lifecycle

What I would like to achieve in a fragment is

1. get the data from network
2. from the data, check which layout I need to inflate

However, the fragment cycle seems to be a sequential flow

That means the `return rootView` is run **before the async task finish**, how to fix it ? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is a good design choice. Before you call this new fragment, in your activity, for example, you could do this checking and start a new fragment with an argument indicating the right layout. Or, you can have two diferent fragments, and start the right you. 
This last choice seems more elegant, since a fragment should encapsulate the layout.

Answer (score 1):

Have the fragment to be added dynamically through code, don't add it until your request returns with the desired layout to be inflated.
Then send the desired layout indicator to the fragment through arguments, and then check the argument and decide which layout to use in your onCreateView()